# Creating animation at runtime in Android

Tags: android

i can use an XML file like below

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

 <translate android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%" android:duration="500" />

</set>
```

and load this xml from code like
AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, com.....R.anim.slidein)

everything works fine

But now for some reason i need to do that same thing without using XML
how do i create the same animation using just code 
i tried something like this

```
TranslateAnimation in = new TranslateAnimation(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);


    in.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(mContext,
                        android.R.anim.accelerate_interpolator));

    in.setDuration(500);
```

but didnt work, nothing animates

i think the problem is with percentages, in the xml i have specified percentages but in the TranslateAnimation constructor how do i specify percentages

Comment: Show us the XML-file and more source code

Comment: What means didn't work? Animation is not played? How are you apply animatin to view? Small note: in XML you use DecelerateInterpolator, but in code you use AccelerateInterpolator.

Comment: I am sorry i didnt post more info, The view is not animating at all, i realize the interpolator but i think that doesnt matter much cause it doesnt animate at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. Constructor that you used creates animation with absolute values (pixels). You need to use [another constructor](http://d.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html#TranslateAnimation%28int,%20float,%20int,%20float,%20int,%20float,%20int,%20float%29). Like this for example:

```
TranslateAnimation in = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, 0, 0.0f, 0, 0.0f);
```

Experiment with first and third parameter. Try use Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (use percent 'p'):

```
 <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0%p" android:duration="500" />
```